# store data into sqlite using Dhtmlx Mobile scheduler

Tags: dhtmlx

I have used mobile scheduler and want to store data into local sqlite database and i am using android application so i have html file,not php.

can anyone help me out to store data into sqlite when add new data from scheduler?

Comment: I have used http://www.dhtmlx.com/ mobile scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use localStorage as datasource. You can [contact DHTMLX](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/contact.shtml) to get the demo for mobile scheduler.